# Why use a timer over a thread, or vice versa?

Tags: java, timer

I've read over a chunk of the answers, which were previously asked by other on Stackoverflow, but I still cannot seem to find a satisfactory answer. I need methods to be continuously running. So, should I run everything through threads, timers, a mix of both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

When an action should be performed at specific intervals or at a specific point in time, it's better to use a timer.

When timing doesn't matter, but a task should be completed ASAP while the program keeps running, you should use a thread.

You wouldn't use a Timer to wait until a file transfer is completed while the user can keep using the rest of the program.

But you wouldn't use a Thread which auto-saves a document every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Even a normal java program (without any Thread) uses concept of thread though we don't realize because there is just one thread. So when ever you want to run something for a longer duration in asynchronous manner Threads are helpful.

So you can use **Timers, Executors or even direct Threads**. Timers or Executor are just abstraction on Threads.